# Make all <div> wrappers the same height, unless 'read more' clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am essentially trying to make a bunch of div tags in two separate columns line up evenly on page load. So for example, the left column has 10 separate 'blocks' and the right has the same. When initially loaded, I want every block to be 200px tall unless a 'read more' button is clicked to expand the content. I currently have:

```
<style type="text/css">.collapse { height: 200px; overflow: hidden; }</style>
<div id="100" class="collapse">
Paragraph content</div>
<a class="vipBUTTON" onclick="document.getElementById('100').style.height = '100%';document.getElementById('100').style.overflow = 'visible';">Read more</a>
```

I have the 'collapse' class currently 200px tall with overflow:none set, so this essentially works - but it can't be closed once opened and from an overall page standpoint will be a pain to manage, as every expanding block will need a unique ID.

Any ideas on how to do this on a large-scale perspective simply? There will likely be 30-40 blocks in each column at times and they should all line up with each other horizontally like blocks stacked on top of each other (unless they are opened).

**I should also note, I can't do this with typical pre-built functionality as each block is wrapped within a table element, as they are generated by a CMS -- and it needs to be pretty easy to manage as a client will be doing it. :-/

---

Here is a Fiddle of what I am working with: http://jsfiddle.net/uazd010m/

---

Comment: Since the CMS is adding extra html you need to provide an example set of 3 to 5 elements so that it can be gauged in a more accurate manner. There is a simple solution, but the tables and elements depending on how they are created could really screw it up.

Comment: Exactly. And sure, let me put together a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/uazd010m/4/

The JS fiddle provided changed how you do the `a` links. I don't use them for javascript or jQuery functions. I think they are very unreliable and limiting. I also added jQuery so you would need to add a valid library if you are not using one. It is possible to use Javascript soley, but I apologize. I don't believe that is the proper solution.

I also added some CSS. I added a `vertical-align` for your `td` base CSS, lower cased `.BUTTON` (reflected by also changing the HTML from `<a class="BUTTON">...` to `<button class=".button">...`... You will need to adjust your css for better looking styles, but that is just an opinion really.

Ask questions if you need.

Comment: I totally understand on your references regarding the <a> links and the CSS. I am working with previous code, trying to add additional functionality so I am a bit limited. But as for the CSS, yes indeed - the fiddle I made looks horrible, but it was just for example. I do believe though, that your solution will work well with some modifications - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For your javascript/jquery, you could go this route:

```
$('.vipBUTTON').on('click', function(){

    if ($(this).prev().height() == '200') {

        $(this).prev().animate({'height':'100%'});

    } else {

       $(this).prev().animate({'height':'200px'});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a common class to these and mimic a focus event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.div').on("click", function () {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

You can also use following [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/7k6rtLbn/).

You can tailor it to fit your needs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great solution, although in my specific situation I don't think it will work. Possibly though, thanks for your time!

Comment: @Ryan: Just out of curiosity, what if a section has too much data (say 2-3 pages). Will user scroll all the way down? and since the width of these sections are not much, small amount of data might cause long scroll. An alternative could be a reading section, like a div fixed to right side of screen that has say 40% width. now user can scroll through this div and header sections remain still. Also you can have this div as resizable div. This might help users in reading big articles.

Comment: I agree this could be a nice functionality add. Although within the product confinements, unfortunately the scrolling will likely be the better option (even though not ideal).

Comment: Following is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/7k6rtLbn/) that you can use if you may require in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html><head></head><body>
    <style type="text/css">.collapse { height: 200px; overflow: hidden; }</style>
    <div id="100" class="collapse">Paragraph content</div>
    <a class="vipBUTTON" onclick="buttonCollapse()">Read more</a>
    <script>
    buttonCollapse = function(){
        var el = document.getElementById( '100' ); // same as document.querySelector( '#100' )
        if( el.className.match( /collapse/ )
            el.className.repalce( /\s*collaspe\s*/, '' );
        else
            el.className += " collapse";
        return true;
    }
    </script>
</body></html>
```

Why jQuery ?
Your function should `return true` for the window. It helps him to work.
Just change the class of your node, it's easiest.